# Is $f_n$ guaranteed to have a pointwise limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of non-negative continuous functions on $[0,1]$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int _0^ 1 f_n(x) dx=0$.

Is $f_n$ guaranteed to have a pointwise limit?

I think the answer is yes but can't prove it.Also I have not got any counter-examples also.Is it true?

Comment: Why can't you just choose $f_n(x) = n$?

Comment: @Hawk Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx\not=0$ . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber, oh that's what we *want*? Oops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n$ be the function defined as follows:

- For ${1\over n}<x\le 1$, $f(x)=0$.
- For $0\le x\le {1\over n}$, the graph of $f$ is a line connecting $(0, \sqrt{n})$ and $({1\over n}, 0)$.

Or, we can define it more symbolically as:

$$ f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n^{1\over 2}-xn^{3\over 2} &\text{ for }\quad 0\le x\le {1\over n}\\0 &\text { for }\quad {1\over n}<x\le 1\end{cases}$$

Then:

- Each $f_n$ is continuous - to see that the two parts of $f_n$ "glue together," note that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow {1\over n}^-}f_n(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow{1\over n}}[n^{1\over 2}-xn^{3\over 2}]=n^{1\over 2}-n^{-1}n^{3\over 2}=n^{1\over 2}-n^{1\over 2}=0=\lim_{x\rightarrow{1\over n}^+}f_n(x);$$
- $\int_0^1f_n(x)dx={1\over 2\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow 0$; but
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: The point is to produce peaks which grow "taller," but are sufficiently "thin" that the limit of the integrals is still zero. There are lots of other ways to do this, too.

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive way of thinking about this is trying to identify a "function" $f$ that is infinity at a single point but equals 0 elsewhere and having the $f_n$ "converge" to $f$. To be more precise, let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions with $\int_0^1 f_n \, \mathrm{d}x = 1/n$ and $\max{f_n} = f(0) = n$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(0)$ doesn't exist so the $f_n$ do not converge pointwise to some function.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative sequence of functions as counterexample:

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} x^n & \text{ if } n \text{ is even}\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases} $$
Then $\int_{0}^1 f_{2n} = \frac{1}{2n+1}$ and $\int_{0}^1 f_{2n+1} = 0$, the $f_n$'s are continuous and non-negative, and yet $f_{2n}(1) = 1$, $f_{2n+1}(1) = 0$ for all $n$ (so that the limit of $f_n(1)$ does not exist).